# "SVN import" imports the content of the project, not the folder

Tags: svn, import

I am trying to import a project (aProject) into the SVN. When I typed this command:

svn import aProject https://.../lamostreta

it imported the content of the aProject, not the aProject folder as a whole. How can I add aProject into SVN repository as a whole?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have always solved this issue was to simple create a temporary folder, move the folder I wanted to version into it, and then run the svn import.

```
mkdir temp
mv aProject temp
svn import temp https://..../repos/repo
mv temp/aProject .
rmdir temp
```

This should take care of it.

Comment: I did
mkdir temp
mv aProject temp
svn import temp https://.../repos/repo
but mv temp/aProject . gave "mv: cannot move temp/aProject Directory not empty" error

Comment: however this state of the svn is also acceptable. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: That second mv command should simply move the folder back out of the temp directory back to its original location. But if it all worked out then that works for me. Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is cause Subversion will assume that you would import the contents of the aProject folder into the folder (lamostreta) in the repository. If you like to have the same folder in your repository you have to give this on command line:

```
   svn import aProject URL/aProject/trunk -m "- First import."
```

Furthermore usually you should give a supplemental folder folder like trunk as target in the repository instead of a bare project name (folder name) like:

```
   svn import aProject URL/aProject -m "- First import."
```

Comment: I understand, I shoul have add project name to the URL. Thanks for the explanation.